# Azure Extensions.json

Tags: cloud, azure-functions

I have created a function app and the basic httptrigger is created using VSCode. I got an error to install the binding extension. How to add extension for queue and blob services. Can anyone help?

Error:

> Function (AutoRestProcessor) Error: The binding type(s) 'queueTrigger' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.
>   Session Id: 3d75c0e67a2148c09615f4e1b1f79169
>   Timestamp: 2018-09-12T17:24:56.675Z

Answer (score 0):

This doc will walk you through installation.  In short if .NET you can install the associated NuGet package.  For Storage Queues it’s `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage`

For non-.NET languages you can opt-into extension bundles that includes a bunch of extensions by default

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register#extension-bundles

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
    }
}
```